# POST: Is it necessary to serialise the JSON data

Tags: python, json, flask-restful

My Rest API works nicely while posting JSON DATA.
I use this on server:

```
req = request.get_json()
dicti = json.loads(req)
#It(dicti) is then processed.
```

On the client, I proceed like this (using python requests):

```
dat = {'a':1, 'b':2}
serialised_dat = json.dumps(dat)
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
requests.post("myurl", json = serialised_dat, headers = headers)
```

And, everything works fine. But, when I go to test my Rest API from other clients like insomnia,
 I get internal server error, which is fair enough because the json, I paste there, is not-serialised.
Do I need to serialise my json and then paste it into other clients to get a success?  OR
Is the method itself, above, I use to send json to flask wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the `json` argument should be an object that will be serialized for you.

```
requests.post("myurl", json=dat, headers=headers)
```

If you have pre-serialized data, use the `data` keyword argument instead.

```
requests.post("myurl", data=json.dumps(dat), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, Sir. Every POST containing a JSON payload would always be serialised, and to process it (on flask) I'd need to use `loads()` to convert it into a dictionary. Is my usage `loads()` on the server for any POST request, irrespective of the client/language correct? If yes, Insomnia gives me error, I paste the raw json there and use the argument `json = dat`